# Unsigned int using ntohs

Tags: c, dns, protocols, endianness

I am getting some data from a DNS server and I am trying to convert a certain part into an unsigned int (which represents the refresh interval, expiration etc). By conversion, I mean from big endian to little endian. The problem is that the ntohs places only 2 bytes of data instead of 4.

```
memcpy(&number, data, 4);
printf("%x ",number);
number = ntohs(number);
printf("%x ",number);

Output:
b6fc0b78 780b
```

About the types:

```
:t data
char*
:t number
unsigned int
```

The weird thing is that even by trying using bit shifts to reconstruct the number, the values are pretty different: like 0, for example.

How could I get 780bfcb6 from b6fc0b78 into an unsigned int?

Comment: Readig documentation could lead to enlightment.

Comment: I did that. But in my documentation that I have been given, the only thing that was said about ntohs was that it is used to convert from network-order to host-order.

Comment: If on a UNIX like system something like `man ntohs` typed in the terminal window mostly is a good reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that `780b` is the byte-swap of `0b78`, which is the low 16 bits of the number you passed in.

The `s` in `ntohs` is for `short`.  It operates on `uint16_t` quantities.  The argument and return type of `ntohs` are `unsigned int` only because it predates C89 prototypes; in K&R C it was impossible to express that a function took an argument shorter than `int`.  (The latest POSIX specification [seems to have decided that this historical wart is no longer necessary](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html).  I *can* persuade GCC and clang to warn about this mistake, but only by using `-Wconversion`, which is not turned on by `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, nor `-pedantic`.)

The function you are looking for is [`ntohl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ntohl.3.html).  It operates on `uint32_t` quantities, which is what you want.  (The `l` is for `long`, but it dates to a time when 64-bit `long` was unheard of.)